# Warning: Undefined array key "submit" in php 8

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

I can't fix this error in php 8!
This problem did not exist in PHP version 7.3!

Warning: Undefined array key "submit" in /home/admin/domains/test.com/public_html/upload/**index.php** on **line 100**

**line 100:
`If(($_POST['submit']==true) AND ($password_form==""))`**

page **index.php:**

```
<?

// Max size PER file in KB
$max_file_size="10240";

// Max size for all files COMBINED in KB
$max_combined_size="40960";

//Maximum file uploades at one time
$file_uploads="4";

//The name of your website
$websitename="Upload center";

// Full browser accessable URL to where files are accessed. With trailing slash.
$full_url="https://www.test/files/";

// Path to store files on your server If this fails use $fullpath below. With trailing slash.
$folder="./files/";

// Use random file names? true=yes (recommended), false=use original file name.
// Random names will help prevent files being denied because a file with that name already exists.
$random_name=true;

// Types of files that are acceptiable for uploading. Keep the array structure.
$allow_types=array("jpg","gif","png","zip","rar","docx","pdf","mp3","mp4","swf");

// Only use this variable if you wish to use full server paths. Otherwise leave this empty. With trailing slash.
$fullpath="";

//Use this only if you want to password protect your upload form.
$password=""; 

/*
//================================================================================
* ! ATTENTION !
//================================================================================
: Don't edit below this line.
*/

// Initialize variables
$password_hash=md5($password);
$error="";
$success="";
$display_message="";
$file_ext=array();
$password_form="";

// Function to get the extension a file.
function get_ext($key) { 
    $key=strtolower(substr(strrchr($key, "."), 1));
    $key=str_replace("jpeg","jpg",$key);
    return $key;
}

// Filename security cleaning. Do not modify.
function cln_file_name($string) {
    $cln_filename_find=array("/\.[^\.]+$/", "/[^\d\w\s-]/", "/\s\s+/", "/[-]+/", "/[_]+/");
    $cln_filename_repl=array("", ""," ", "-", "_");
    $string=preg_replace($cln_filename_find, $cln_filename_repl, $string);
    return trim($string);
}

// If a password is set, they must login to upload files.
If($password) {
    
    //Verify the credentials.
    If($_POST['verify_password']==true) {
        If(md5($_POST['check_password'])==$password_hash) {
            setcookie("phUploader",$password_hash);
            sleep(1); //seems to help some people.
            header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            exit;
        }
    }

    //Show the authentication form
    If($_COOKIE['phUploader']!=$password_hash) {
        $password_form="<form method=\"POST\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">\n";
        $password_form.="<table align=\"center\" class=\"table\">\n";
        $password_form.="<tr>\n";
        $password_form.="<td width=\"100%\" class=\"table_header\" colspan=\"2\">Password Required</td>\n";
        $password_form.="</tr>\n";
        $password_form.="<tr>\n";
        $password_form.="<td width=\"35%\" class=\"table_body\">Enter Password:</td>\n";
        $password_form.="<td width=\"65%\" class=\"table_body\"><input type=\"password\" name=\"check_password\" /></td>\n";
        $password_form.="</tr>\n";
        $password_form.="<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\" class=\"table_body\">\n";
        $password_form.="<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"verify_password\" value=\"true\">\n";
        $password_form.="<input type=\"submit\" value=\" Verify Password \" />\n";
        $password_form.="</td>\n";
        $password_form.="</tr>\n";
        $password_form.="</table>\n";
        $password_form.="</form>\n";
    }
    
} // If Password

// Dont allow submit if $password_form has been populated
If(($_POST['submit']==true) AND ($password_form=="")) {

    //Tally the size of all the files uploaded, check if it's over the ammount. 
    If(array_sum($_FILES['file']['size']) > $max_combined_size*1024) {
        
        $error.="<b>FAILED:</b> All Files <b>REASON:</b> Combined file size is to large.<br />";
        
    // Loop though, verify and upload files.
    } Else {

        // Loop through all the files.
        For($i=0; $i <= $file_uploads-1; $i++) {
            
            // If a file actually exists in this key
            If($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) {

                //Get the file extension
                $file_ext[$i]=get_ext($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
                
                // Randomize file names
                If($random_name){
                    $file_name[$i]=time()+rand(0,1000000);
                } Else {
                    $file_name[$i]=cln_file_name($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
                }
    
                // Check for blank file name
                If(str_replace(" ", "", $file_name[$i])=="") {
                    
                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> Blank file name detected.<br />";
                
                //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
                }   ElseIf(!in_array($file_ext[$i], $allow_types)) {
                                
                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> Invalide file type.<br />";
                                
                //Check the size of each file
                } Elseif($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] > ($max_file_size*1024)) {
                    
                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> File to large.<br />";
                    
                // Check if the file already exists on the server..
                } Elseif(file_exists($folder.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i])) {
    
                    $error.= "<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> File already exists.<br />";
                    
                } Else {
                    
                    If(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$folder.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i])) {
                        
                        $success.="<b>SUCCESS:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]."<br />";
                        $success.="<b>URL:</b> <a href=\"".$full_url.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$full_url.$file_name[$i].".".$file_ext[$i]."</a><br /><br />";
                        
                    } Else {
                        $error.="<b>FAILED:</b> ".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." <b>REASON:</b> General upload failure.<br />";
                    }
                    
                }
                            
            } // If Files
        
        } // For
        
    } // Else Total Size
    
    If(($error=="") AND ($success=="")) {
        $error.="<b>FAILED:</b> No files selected<br />";
    }

    $display_message=$success.$error;

} // $_POST AND !$password_form

/*
//================================================================================
* Start the form layout
//================================================================================
:- Please know what your doing before editing below. Sorry for the stop and start php.. people requested that I use only html for the form..
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" sizes="24x24">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $websitename; ?> - test</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #000000;
    }
    
    .message {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11pt;
        color: #000000;
        background-color:#EBEBEB;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    a:link, a:visited {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #000000;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        width:500px;
    }
    
    .table_header {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        background-color:#C03738;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13pt;
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align:center;
        padding:4px;
    }
    
    .upload_info {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        background-color:#EBEBEB;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11pt;
        color: #000000;
        padding:4px;
        line-height: 23px;
    }

    .table_body {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        background-color:#EBEBEB;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: #000000;
        padding:2px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    .table_footer {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        background-color:#C03738;
        text-align:center;
        padding:3px;
    }

    input,select,textarea {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #000000;
        background-color:#AFAEAE;
        border:1px solid #000000;
    }
    
    .copyright {
        border:0px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #000000;
        text-align:right;
        line-height:40px;
    }
    
    form {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
.table { width:95%; }
.upload_info { width: 95%; }
.table_footer { width: 95%; }
.table_header { width: 95%; }
.table_body { width: 100%; }
}

.style1 {
                font-family: Tahoma;
}
</style>

<?
If($password_form) {
    
    Echo $password_form;

} Else {
?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="phuploader">
<table align="center" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="table_header" colspan="2"><b><?=$websitename;?></b> </td>
    </tr>

    <?If($display_message){?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="message">
        <br />
            <?=$display_message;?>
        <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?}?>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="upload_info">
            <b>Allowed Types:</b> <?=implode($allow_types, ", ");?><br />
            <b>Max size per file:</b> <?=$max_file_size?>kb.<br />
            <b>Max size for all files combined:</b> <?=$max_combined_size?>kb.<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?For($i=0;$i <= $file_uploads-1;$i++) {?>
        <tr>
            <td class="table_body" width="20%"><b>Select File:</b> </td>
            <td class="table_body" width="80%"><input type="file" name="file[]" size="30" /></td>
        </tr>
    <?}?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="table_footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />
            <input type="submit" value=" Upload File(s) " /> &nbsp;
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value=" Reset Form " onclick="window.location.reload(true);" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?}//Please leave this here.. it really dosen't make people hate you or make your site look bad.. ?>
<table class="table" style="border:0px;" align="center">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"This problem did not exist in PHP version 7.3!"_... I assure you it did, you probably just had a different error reporting configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use like this:

```
If((isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']==true) AND ($password_form==""))
```